# Validate with XSD that XML contains nodes with exact values

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have some XML:

```
<common>
    <parameter>
        <name>Param1</name>
        <value>Value1</value>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <name>Param2</name>
        <value>Value2</value>
    </parameter>
</common>
```

I need to validate that there is exact 2 parameters with exact 2 names: Param1, Param2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="common" type="CommonType" />

    <xs:complexType name="CommonType">
        <xs:sequence>  
            <xs:element name="parameter" type="ParameterType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />  
        </xs:sequence> 
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ParameterType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="ParameterNameType"/>
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="ParameterNameType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:normalizedString">
            <xs:enumeration value="Param1" minOccurs="1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Param2" minOccurs="1" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

In restriction section there is `minOccurs` attribute that is invalid in XSD. How can i implement a such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="common">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>  
                <xs:element name="parameter" type="ParameterType" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2" />  
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="uniqueAuthor">
            <xs:selector xpath="parameter"/>
            <xs:field xpath="name"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="ParameterType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="ParameterNameType"/>
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="ParameterNameType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:normalizedString">
            <xs:enumeration value="Param1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Param2" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why specify the names of the parameters as values of the elements?  Why not specify them as the names of the elements?  In that case, the required declarations are trivial.